# Libgdx touchDragged() method

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I badly need help right now.
I am making a game just like candy crush using **LIBGDX** in android. Im having hard time in the `touchDragged()` method of the interface `InputProcessor`. This code supposedly to be able to detect a swipe up, swipe left, swipe down, and swipe right without lifting the touch. But its a bit different, swipe left means, i touch the candy(touchCandy) then drag to the 1 position to the left Candy of the touchcandy, etc.
I have a `class Candy extends Actor`. and this is my code of my inputprocessor:

```
Actor hitActor;
boolean touched;
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    touched = true;
    touchVector = new Vector3(screenX,screenY,0);
    game.getCamera().unproject(touchVector);
    hitActor = stage.hit(touchVector.x,touchVector.y,false);
    }

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(touched==true)
    {
     Actor hitDraggedActor;
     Vector3 touchVectorDragged = new Vector3(screenX,screenY,0);
     game.getCamera().unproject(touchVectorDragged);
     hitDraggedActor = stage.hit(touchVectorDragged.x,touchVectorDragged.y,false);
     if(hitDraggedActor!=hitActor) //<--i tried !hitDraggedActor.equals(hitActor)
     {
       Candy hitDraggedCandy = (Candy) hitDraggedActor;
       Candy hitCandy = (Candy) hitActor;
       //print attributes of hitDraggedCandy and hitCandy
      // result is similar when in fact, it should not
       //do something here
     }
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    touched=false;
    return false;
}
```

Moreover, when I castdown the hitActor and hitDraggedActor to my Candy Class, it is the same, like when i print the attributes it prints the same.
If there is something i need to clarify, please comment it.
If someone could enlighten me, that would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Sorry my bad, i was printing the same thing. There was no error on the above code.
Gdx.app.log("DEBUG","x="+x+",y="+x);
should be: Gdx.app.log("DEBUG","x="+x+",y="+y);

Comment: Sorry, my bad. there was no error from the above code. I was printing this Gdx.app.log("LOG","x="+x+",y="+x); instead of
Gdx.app.log("LOG","x="+x+",y="+y);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect swipe up, down, left and right, then this code would be better

```js
public class SimpleDirectionGestureDetector extends GestureDetector {
 public interface DirectionListener {
  void onLeft();

  void onRight();

  void onUp();

  void onDown();
 }

 public SimpleDirectionGestureDetector(DirectionListener directionListener) {
  super(new DirectionGestureListener(directionListener));
 }
 
 private static class DirectionGestureListener extends GestureAdapter{
  DirectionListener directionListener;
  
  public DirectionGestureListener(DirectionListener directionListener){
   this.directionListener = directionListener;
  }
  
  @Override
        public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
   if(Math.abs(velocityX)>Math.abs(velocityY)){
    if(velocityX>0){
      directionListener.onRight();
    }else{
      directionListener.onLeft();
    }
   }else{
    if(velocityY>0){
      directionListener.onDown();
    }else{                                  
      directionListener.onUp();
    }
   }
   return super.fling(velocityX, velocityY, button);
        }

 }

}
```

After that you can set your input processor to an instance of that class like this

```js
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new SimpleDirectionGestureDetector(new SimpleDirectionGestureDetector.DirectionListener() {
  
 @Override
 public void onUp() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 }

 @Override
 public void onRight() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void onLeft() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void onDown() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }
}));
```

Now you can implement your own logic in the onUp, onDown, onLeft and onRight methods of the listener. This code is taken from [another website](https://truongtx.me/2013/04/27/simple-swipe-gesture-detection-for-libgdx/)